# In R, I need to divide a set of numbers by a specific value in another column and then repeat that action by grouped variables

Tags: r, dplyr

I have some educational data that includes school names, school year, ethnicity, and a count of classes taken and students that took those classes.

```
structure(list(SchoolName = c("BHS", "BHS", "BHS", "BHS", "BHS", 
"BHS"), CourseSchoolYear = c("2017-18", "2017-18", "2017-18", 
"2017-18", "2017-18", "2017-18"), Category = c("Asian", "Black", 
"Hispanic", "Other", "Overall", "White"), `Total Population` = c(129, 
53, 173, 133, 1932, 1444), `Theatre Classes` = c(9, 0, 11, 8, 
126, 98), `Music Classes` = c(73, 7, 91, 60, 990, 759), `Visual Arts Classes` = c(52, 
26, 69, 52, 770, 571), `Total Arts Classes` = c(167, 42, 203, 
144, 2359, 1803), `# of Students All Art` = c(90, 28, 106, 77, 
1241, 940), `# of Students Theatre` = c(7, 0, 8, 7, 97, 75), 
    `# of Students Music` = c(37, 4, 41, 27, 460, 351), `# of Students Visual Arts` = c(41, 
    19, 53, 40, 599, 446)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Here is a snippet of one school for one school year. I need to divide the values of each ethnicity by the overall population value. But I need to do it for each type of course. And THEN I need to repeat this action for 80 more schools, with 5 years of data each. I know there must be some type of loop or function I could write but I am too new to R programming to figure it out.

Comment: I should be more clear, I need to divide the values from each ethnicity by the single overall population value for that school. So in this case, 1932. Obviously, this is different for each school and year.

Comment: Can you please check my updated answer

Comment: Can you give the desired output for this sample input so possible solutions can be tested and verified to work?

Comment: @RonakPatel Initially I had the answer where I was subsetting the Total Populatioin based on 'Overall', I changed my answer to that based on your comment on other answer

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If we are dividing the columns based on the 'Total Population'

```
library(dplyr)
df2 <- df1 %>%
         group_by(SchoolName, CourseSchoolYear) %>%
         mutate_at(vars(`Theatre Classes`:`# of Students Visual Arts`),
                  list(perc =  ~ ./`Total Population`[Category == "Overall"]))
```

Comment: This is great, thanks.
I also need to divide each Arts Classes columns ethnicity by the overall number of students taking that type of course. So, for example, I need to divide each ethnicity under Music Classes by the total number of students taking Music classes that year. Again, this needs to be repeated by all the schools and each of the years. How would I change the code you provided to add that?

Comment: Sorry, yes you did. Didn't realize I could only check one answer as the correct one. New to Stack Overflow/R. Had one more question I was hoping you could help with: 
I also need to divide each Arts Classes columns ethnicity by the overall number of students taking that type of course. So, for example, I need to divide each ethnicity under Music Classes by the total number of students taking Music classes that year. Again, this needs to be repeated by all the schools and each of the years. How would I change the code you provided to add that?

Comment: @RonakPatel Do you need `mutate_at(vars(`Theatre Classes`:`# of Students Visual Arts`), list(perc = ~ ./sum(`Total Population`))` or `list(perc = ~ ./sum(.)))`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, all values need to be divided by a single value per school and year which is the `Total Population` in category `Overall`.

This requires a modification of [akrun's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60066215/3817004):

```
df3 <- df1 %>%
  group_by(SchoolName, CourseSchoolYear) %>%
  mutate_at(vars(`Theatre Classes`:`# of Students Visual Arts`),
            list(share =  ~ ./`Total Population`[Category == "Overall"]))
```

which produces

```
df3 %>% 
  select(c(SchoolName:`Total Population`, ends_with("share")))
```

> ```
> # A tibble: 6 x 12
> # Groups:   SchoolName, CourseSchoolYear [1]
>   SchoolName CourseSchoolYear Category `Total Populati… `Theatre Classe… `Music Classes_… `Visual Arts Cl… `Total Arts Cla…
>   <chr>      <chr>            <chr>               <dbl>            <dbl>            <dbl>            <dbl>            <dbl>
> 1 BHS        2017-18          Asian                 129          0.00466          0.0378            0.0269           0.0864
> 2 BHS        2017-18          Black                  53          0                0.00362           0.0135           0.0217
> 3 BHS        2017-18          Hispanic              173          0.00569          0.0471            0.0357           0.105 
> 4 BHS        2017-18          Other                 133          0.00414          0.0311            0.0269           0.0745
> 5 BHS        2017-18          Overall              1932          0.0652           0.512             0.399            1.22  
> 6 BHS        2017-18          White                1444          0.0507           0.393             0.296            0.933 
> # … with 4 more variables: `# of Students All Art_share` <dbl>, `# of Students Theatre_share` <dbl>, `# of Students
> #   Music_share` <dbl>, `# of Students Visual Arts_share` <dbl>
> ```

---

I find it irritating that the `Overall` row appears among the rows of the ethnicities. Here is a way to make this the last row for each school and year:

```
df3 <- df1 %>%
  mutate(Category = forcats::fct_relevel(Category, "Overall", after = Inf)) %>% 
  arrange(SchoolName, CourseSchoolYear, Category) %>% 
  group_by(SchoolName, CourseSchoolYear) %>%
  mutate_at(vars(`Theatre Classes`:`# of Students Visual Arts`),
            list(share =  ~ ./`Total Population`[Category == "Overall"]))

df3 %>% 
  select(c(SchoolName:`Total Population`, ends_with("share")))
```

> ```
> # A tibble: 6 x 12
> # Groups:   SchoolName, CourseSchoolYear [1]
>   SchoolName CourseSchoolYear Category `Total Populati… `Theatre Classe… `Music Classes_… `Visual Arts Cl… `Total Arts Cla…
>   <chr>      <chr>            <fct>               <dbl>            <dbl>            <dbl>            <dbl>            <dbl>
> 1 BHS        2017-18          Asian                 129          0.00466          0.0378            0.0269           0.0864
> 2 BHS        2017-18          Black                  53          0                0.00362           0.0135           0.0217
> 3 BHS        2017-18          Hispanic              173          0.00569          0.0471            0.0357           0.105 
> 4 BHS        2017-18          Other                 133          0.00414          0.0311            0.0269           0.0745
> 5 BHS        2017-18          White                1444          0.0507           0.393             0.296            0.933 
> 6 BHS        2017-18          Overall              1932          0.0652           0.512             0.399            1.22  
> # … with 4 more variables: `# of Students All Art_share` <dbl>, `# of Students Theatre_share` <dbl>, `# of Students
> #   Music_share` <dbl>, `# of Students Visual Arts_share` <dbl>
> ```

Comment: thanks, i think this gets me what i need. can you please explain the 'mutate_at(vars(`Theatre Classes`:`# of Students Visual Arts`),
            list(share =  ~ ./`Total Population`[Category == "Overall"]))' part, as i may have to use this solution in a few different ways and want to learn the basis of the commands.